# Skip counting user's own comment

Tags: mysql, join

I thought it would be a simple query, but it's harder than I expected.

I have a simply forum application where users open a story then other users can post comments.

Two tables are

**Stories**

```
id
user_id
subject
approved
```

**Comments**

```
id
user_id
story_id
approved
```

Basically, I would like to query unanswered stories by not counting original poster's own comment. Even if someone else posts a new comment, it should not be considered as an answered story when the comment is not approved yet.

```
select * from stories left join comments on stories.id = comments.story_id
having count(comments.id) = 0 or ( count(comments.id) > 0 and comments.user_id = stories.user_id )
```

It works fine without the 'approved' flag, but I just can't make it work when I add 'approved' into where/having clause.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd move the `count` into a subquery and put in  an `in` condition to check what's answered and what isn't:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM   stories s
WHERE  s.id NOT IN (SELECT   story_id
                    FROM     comments c
                    WHERE    approved = true AND 
                             c.user_id != s.user_id 
                    GROUP BY story_id
                    HAVING   COUNT(*) > 0)
```

Comment: Thank you @Mureinik! This seems work. Just a newbie question...is it supposed to be slower than join + having?

Comment: @Moon It **shouldn't** be, but this is really hard to answer without profiling it on your actual dataset.

Comment: // Thank you! I will run a profiling within my limited knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Try this untested query:

```
select * 
from stories 
   left join comments on stories.id = comments.story_id and comments.user_id <> stories.user_id 
having count(comments.id) = 0
```

Comment: Thank you @Jens, but it's not working. I don't get anything back.